# Getting FFmpeg error when combining 3 filters into one: “Filter setsar has a unconnected output.”

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine 3 videos into one.  2 are sourced from a surveillance system, the 3rd is a placeholder JPEG that I looped in to a video using this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i FULL.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1920:1080,setsar=sar=189/190,setdar=16/9" -filter:v fps=fps=1 placeholder.mp4
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the sar.  Because when I combine the 3 files via

```
ffmpeg -i BEGINNING.mp4 -i placeholder.mp4 -i END.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[1:v]setsar=sar=189/190[v1];[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][3:a][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" full_demo.mp4
```

I get:

```
Filter setsar has a unconnected output
```

The sar of BEGINNING.mp4 and END.mp4 are 189/190 according to their mediainfo output.  When I run mediainfo on placeholder.mp4, there is no sar or dar returned.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to input the modified stream to concat, not the original stream, so

```
[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][3:a][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]
```

becomes

```
[0:v:0][0:a:0][v1][3:a][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1[v][a]
```

Also, in your first command, only the fps filter is applied. Multiple filters should be applied in a chain. Also, setsar and setdar both operate upon the same parameter. DAR = SAR x WIDTH / HEIGHT. So,

```
-vf "scale=1920:1080,setdar=16/9,fps=fps=1"
```

Comment: Ok, fixed the first command, thanks for the extra info.

Comment: I did the math and came up with `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i FULL.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1920:1080,setdar=1.768,fps=fps=1" placeholder.mp4` then `ffmpeg -i BEGINNING.mp4 -i placeholder.mp4 -i END.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][3:a][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" full_demo.mp4` and that kicks back `[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x19d6c60] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 891:896) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x1080, SAR 189:190)`

Comment: Edited concat args.

Comment: Ok, making progress.  It did spit out a video, but placeholder.mp4 was completely omitted, it went from BEGINNING.mp4 right into END.mp4.  During the process, it kicked out **a lot** of these errors:
`[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x1159700] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.trate=1512.5kbits/s
    Last message repeated 8 times`
and
`Past duration 0.602913 too large`

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg to recent git or 4.1 and check.